# A square has sides $ l=\frac14$. The probability to pick a point at random on perimeter is equal to the length of the side. Find the CDF.

Tags: probability, density-function

> A square has sides $ l=\frac14$. The probability to pick a point at random on perimeter is equal to the length of the side. Let X= the x coordinate of the point picked. Find the CDF.

This question has been solve before, yet I'm having difficulty understanding the solution given.

$P(X=0)= \frac14$

This I understand but:

For $0\lt x \le 0.25:$

$P(X=0)+P(0\lt x \le 0.25)= \frac14 + 2x$

What is the reasoning behind the 2x?

I understand the probability of picking a point at x=0.125 is half.

Comment: I reckon $X$ stands for a random variable here, and $x$ does not. The notation $P(0<x\leq0.25)$ makes no sense. You need something like $P(X\leq x)=\frac14+2x$ if $0\leq x<0.25$ together wit $P(X\leq x)=1$ if $x\geq0.25$ and $P(X\leq x)=0$ if $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $\mathbb{P}[X=0] = \mathbb{P}[X = 1/4] = 1/4$ since this means you picked a point on the corresponding vertical edge.

So, $\mathbb{P}[X \le 0] = 1/4$ and $\mathbb{P}[X < 1/4] = 0.75$, and you need linear growth in the middle because of the uniformity of the pick.

Comment: I thought $P(X \lt 0)= 0 $? 

Also, might there be a more intuitive explanation ?

Comment: @drhab typo, $1/4$ not 1...

Comment: @RonaldB indeed $\mathbb{P}[X < 0] = 0$ but $\mathbb{P}[X \le 0] = \mathbb{P}[X=0] = 1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\leq x<\frac14$ then: $$F(x)=\Pr(X\leq x)=\Pr(X<0)+\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(0<X\leq x)=0+\frac14+2x$$

Here $\frac14$ is the measure of $\{\langle 0,t\rangle\mid 0<t\leq \frac14\}$.

Here $2x$ is the sum of the measures of $\{\langle s,0\rangle\mid 0<s\leq x\}$ and $\{\langle s,\frac14\rangle\mid 0<s\leq x\}$.

Denoting the $3$ mentioned sets by $A,B,C$ we have: $$X\leq x\iff \langle X,Y\rangle \in A\cup B\cup C$$

Also note that the $A,B,C$ are disjoint.